# Adding anonymous provider to Angular module written in TypeScript

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript, adal

Is it possible to inject (anonymously) provider out of `.js` file into angular module written using typescript? I am trying to compile typescript which fails inside module definition.

Story

I have a basic enough module written using angular in typescript notation. I am trying to add a definition for `adalAuthenticationService` provider into the mix from `adal-angular.js`. Because provider is not in `.d.ts` format I can't use it as a reference. Converting provider to `.d.ts` is out of the question for now. So I am left with anonymous injection option (if there is such an option).

Controller definition

```
module Temp.NewModule {
     interface IMainCtl {
         init(): void;
         b1(): void;
         b2(): void;
     }

     class MainCtl implements IMainCtl {
         hello: string;    
         txtb1: string;
         txtb2: string;

         // not sure what effect {private adalService: any} has as it doesn't seem to provide anonymity
         constructor(private $scope, private $log: ng.ILogService, private Api: IApi, private adalService: any) {
             var vm = this;
             this.init();
             // not sure if this actually does anything
             var adalService = adalAuthenticationService;
         }

         public init() {
             this.Api.getDataRx().subscribe((result) => {
                 this.hello = result.data.Name;
             });
         }

         public helloWorld() {
             this.$log.info('I accept your greeting');
         }

         public b1() {
            this.txtb1 = 'Now Button 1 works';
         }

         public b2() {
            // i am trying to call login function of adalService provider
            adalService.login();
         }
     }
     // i am trying to inject adalService provider here
     app.controller('MainCtl', ['$scope','$log','Api', MainCtl, adalService]);
 }
```

App definition

```
module Temp {
    export module NewModule {
        export var serviceRoot: string = NewModule.serviceRoot || "";
        export var templatePath: string;
        export var servicesFramework: any;


        //Initalizes angular app
        $("html").attr("ng-app", "NewModule");
        export var app: ng.IModule = angular.module('NewModule', ['rx', 'ngRoute', 'AdalAngular'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider) {
            adalProvider
            .init ({
                tenant: 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com',
                clientId: 'client_id',
                extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
                //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
            },
            $httpProvider
            );
        }]);

    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to bypass the compilation stage with `adalAuthenticationService` injected as a dependency because `adal-angular.js` is included. So in theory it should get picked up once page renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is wrong, you are injecting adalService after your controller. Furthermore, from adal documentation, the service is called adalAuthenticationService. Try something like:

```
 app.controller('MainCtl', ['$scope','$log','Api', 'adalAuthenticationService', MainCtl]);
```

Anonymous injection is totally supported, you don't even need to specify any. If you do not specifiy anything, it will be considered as any.
If you want to take advantage of IntelliSense, you can write only what you need in an `adal.d.ts` file without having to complete everything.

In your b2 function, you forgot a this:

```
public b2() {
    // i am trying to call login function of adalService provider
    this.adalService.login();
}
```

Comment: Yep been trying that from the start and same result. keeps telling me that ``adalServices`` is undefined.

Comment: From the documentation, the service is called `adalAuthenticationService` and not `adalService`. Might it be just that?

Comment: No I don't think its that. I tried ``adalAuthenticationService`` and ``adalAuthenticationServiceProvider`` too. My suspiciaon is that becuase I am trying to include it from ``.js`` file while compiler expects to find relevant definition in ``.d.ts`` file it fails to compile. In other words compiler doesn't actually know where to find the definition. That is why I am looking for a way to include it as anonymously typed defintion. Something equvalent of using anonymously typed var ``declare var MyPoint: { x: number; y: number; };``.

Comment: Anonymous type should work just fine. You forgot a this in front of the adalService in you b2 function. I updated my answer with (hopefully) working code.

Comment: Nope, sorry I also tried that. While this helps to alleviate the error message happening at function ``b2`` I am still unable to compile. Error message that I keep getting ``Cannot find name 'adalService'``. This changes depending on what name I sub into ``app.controller``. Hense why I need to instruct compiler not to worry about finding ``adalService`` at compile time because it is something that will be available at run time.

Comment: I updated my answer again. Make sure that your service is injected before your function, and that it is properly named.

Comment: You are the guru. I've added ``'adalAuthenticationService'`` as you suggested and everything compiled. Thank you for the help.